# Change default asp.net mvc5 validation messages

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

This is my model's date property:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy.mm.dd}")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "You need to fill this")]
[DataType(DataType.DateTime, ErrorMessage = "Type proper date")]
[Display(Name = "Weight Date")]
public DateTime? WeightDate { get; set; }
```

This is how I render bootstrap's `datepicker`

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.WeightDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id="WeightDate" @class = "form-control datepicker", @required = "required" }})
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.WeightDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Validation seems to working (I can see "You need to fill this" when entering empty `datepicker` value). The problem is that I can see other messages, which I would don't want to see (or at least change their messages):

When I enter invalid data, I am getting error (from client side):

```
The field Weight date must be a date.
```

When I submit invalid data, I am getting error (from server side):

```
The value '202441.02.03' is not valid for Weight date.
```

How can I change those messages?

Comment: Maybe you need to create custom validation attributes to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Did you build your project (Ctrl + Shift + B) after making changes to these attributes?

Comment: @RohanRao Yes. I already solved this my making own `ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider.ResourceClassKey` and`DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey`.